# Ready functions elements created by events not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Before reading my problem, The global question is : i create elements with jQuery with click event, and i have ready functions for these elements before being created, but these ready functions won't work only when i create those elements by hand.

I'm using jQuery in this process.

First Part :

Ii have a link (#addBefore) with an click event that creates elements (file input fields) with insertBefore method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var num = 1;
    $("#addREA").click(function() {
        num = num + 1;
        if (num <= 4) {
           $("
        <div class='col-lg-8'>
           <div class='text-center'>
              <div class=''>
                  <img src='' class='FILE_REA" + num + " img-responsive'/>
              </div>
      <h4>Charger une autre image d'illustration...</h4>
      <input type='file' name='ctl00$MainContent$FILE_REA" + num + "' id='ctl00_MainContent_FILE_REA" + num + "'/>
             </div>
        </div>")
       .insertBefore("#addbefore");
        }
    });
```

});

In this process i create each time a new id concatenated with num.

Second Part :

And i have a function that previews each image after being selected in the input

```
function readURL1(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('.FILE_REA1').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#ctl00_MainContent_FILE_REA1").change(function() {
    readURL1(this);
});
```

I copied this function four times, in each i change, the img className and the input id with the ones i created in Part 1 :

As logical as it seems to me, this doesn't do it, when i create elements with plain html it works, but like this it doesn't.

Thank's for your help

If i didn't explain well my issue, please just answer me about the first one, thank you.

Please take a look here the full example : 
http://jsfiddle.net/j5owj8p1/

Comment: You need to escape the linebreaks. `...>\\`

Comment: Rather than posting portions of larger files, could you try using a site like [jsbin](//jsbin.com) to create a small standalone example that shows the problem? Sometimes, this can help you better understand the problem as well.

Comment: Ok i added the link to jsfiddle, it's still not working, thank's

Answer (score 0):

I should link the event to the object to be created with `.on` method

```
 $(document).on('change','#FILE_REA1',function(){
        alert("changed3");
        readURL1(this);
    });
```

that's why id didn't work
Thank's, hope it'll help others.